# How do I determine what android widget is calling my function?

Tags: java, android, resources, seekbar

I have several `SeekBar`s in an Android app that do practically the same thing (set bass, treble, volume).  To save typing out new local classes for `OnSeekBarChangeListener` per `SeekBar`, I tried to make a single class that in its `onStopTrackingTouch` would determine which widget was calling it, and do the proper action.

```
public class mySeekBar implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    int progressChanged = 0;

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
        progressChanged = progress;
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
          // i want a case statement here switched on the widget ID/name, so 
          // i can set the appropriate string s (bass, treble, volume)
        String s = "set_treble " + progressChanged;
        client.sendMessage(s);
    }

}
```

How do I figure out which widget is calling the `onStopTrackingTouch`?  Or is there a cleaner or better way of doing this?

Comment: you have SeekBar seekBar parameter, dont you?

Comment: `SeekBar` inderectly extends `View` which has a `getId()` method to get the resource id of the `View` (in this case the `SeekBar` passed into the `onStopTrackingTouch(...)` method. Simply use a `switch / case` statement on the resource id returned by `seekbar.getId()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**100 % you can determine like this;**

```
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
          // i want a case statement here switched on the widget ID/name, so 
          // i can set the appropriate string s (bass, treble, volume)
        String s = "set_treble " + progressChanged;
        client.sendMessage(s);

       switch (seekBar.getId()) {
                case R.id.seekVolume:

                    break;
                case R.id.bass:
                    break;
                case R.id.trouble:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
    }
```

Comment: Well that was fast, it works perfectly.  In retrospect it was a pretty dumb question, but I'm just learning OO and Java....    Thanks.